# Calculate Correlations of Pairs of Columns in a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, apply, correlation

I have the following dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- data.frame(a1 = rnorm(5) , b1 = rnorm(5), c1 = rnorm(5),  a2 = rnorm(5), b2 = rnorm(5), c2 = rnorm(5))
```

I would like to obtain the correlations of the pairs of columns:
cor(a1,a2), cor(b1,b2), cor(c1,c2)

I tried the following but NA's appear as output:

```
apply(y,2,function(x) cor(x[1],x[3]))
```

I would like to get the result equivalent to

```
cor(y[,1],y[,4])
cor(y[,2],y[,5])
cor(y[,3],y[,6])
```

In my actual data frame, I have many more pairs of columns.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: If you don't mind extra output, you could just do `cor(y)`?

Comment: why not just replace the x[n] with y[n] instead?

Comment: I do mind extra output since there are too many variables in my actual data frame. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
num.vars <- length(y)
var1 <- head(names(y), num.vars / 2)
var2 <- tail(names(y), num.vars / 2)
mapply(cor, y[var1], y[var2])
#         a1         b1         c1 
#  0.2491625 -0.5313192  0.5594564
```

Comment: classy! what if you  if num.vars is odd?

Comment: It shouldn't be the case given how the OP posed the problem. But I suppose how `var1` and `var2` are created could use different approaches (e.g. a regex). I would leave the `mapply` alone though.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using variable regular expression on names. This works also if variable names are in arbitrary order.

```
nn <- 
unique(sub('([0-9]+)','',names(y )))

sapply(nn,function(x){
    xy = y[,grep(x,names(y))]
    cor(xy[,1],xy[,2])})
         a          b          c 
-0.7615458  0.5683647  0.5594564
```